# partition moving crashed mid-process - what damage have it done / what to do ? (AOMEI app used)

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, partition-recovery

- I used AOMEI Partition Assistant Pro (5.x) to "Align" an NTFS partition with about 170GB of data. (Cca 800GB partition on standard (non SSD) 1TB hard disk).
- The app started after reboot in "PreOS" mode.
- The process screen actually sayd "Moving partition". I guess thats what "aligning" actually does - move the partition to new position (?)
- The app got to phase "Moving data: 50 GB/170 GB".
- Then the app crashed and computer suddenly shut down. In mid-process, while working with / changing the partition data. I'm guessing it was somewhere 1/3 to 1/2 through the 170GB of data.
- Since the partition moving process didn't finish, I believe (from my past experience) it must have corrupted the partition - the file system on it.
- I disconnected the HDD with the partition so OS can't do any more damage to the corrupted filesystem.
- I contacted AOMEI support:

  - The basic level support told me that if I can view content of the partition then no damage was done to it. With all respect I highly doubt that.
  - Also they told me they'll pass the problem to "research team". I didn't hear from them since (more then 2 weeks now since).
- I checked the partition via Windows and I can see (some) dirs there. I didn't try to access any.
- I ren checkdisk in readonly (no repair) mode on the partition and it reported a lot of index errors in 1st step. So it seems that there are problems.

Since the AOMEI support left me hanging I'd like to ask for help and advice here.

I am not an expert on filesystems / partitions so I don't know.. **Can you give me some technical informations about what was the app actually doing with the partition and files data when moving them ?**
So I can get an idea about what damage it could have done to the data and find best way to attempt to fix it with least data loss.

I understand that you are not AOMEI devs and don't know *exactly* how the app works but I hope you can make some educated guesses.

Many thanks.

*(The partition countains stored data of past several years of my work. I'm a game/software developer. I depend on that data and I'm really scared I may lose them or some part of them!
Plus as ex basic system admin I have a previous experience with unfinished partition operation that resulted in half of data being lost.)*

Comment: If the old and new partitions have any overlap, I hope you made a backup.  If there is no overlap, the source partition should've been untouched.

Comment: I could attempt to write out some guesses here, but I think we can help you more thoroughly by [chatting](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) about it interactively, and if we come to any conclusions we can post them as an answer here...

Comment: @Ricky - Im afraid they definitely overlap. It was partition "aligning" which - Im guessing here - just moves the whole partition by several kBytes to align it with HDD's inner indexing (?)